# Is 'event' argument optional when listening to events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Is '**event**' argument optional when using `addEventListener` function?

If no, then why those two snippets work the same and which is better to use?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        });
```

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            });
```

Comment: It's better to use the second example. I'm not even sure why the first works at all since event isn't being defined

Comment: @Ivar I never even thought that `event` could be a global property

Comment: @evolutionxbox It shouldn't have been really... But someone once thought it was useful, and then it needed to keep working for the sake of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was a Microsoft decision (originally) and now we're stuck with it.